# DHT11 sensor failure on Edison whereas working successful on RPi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, sensors, intel-edison

Some time ago I was connecting DHT11 sensor to Arduino UNO and wrote [a simple library](https://gist.github.com/onegrx/7c467698c63850e193f7a5edd88a4108) based on [the one from Arduino website](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DHT11Lib).

At the moment I'd like to connect DHT11 to Intel Edison with Arduino Expansion Board running Yocto Linux. While trying to rewrite the library to Python I expected a problem with microseconds's sleeps in that language and finally decided to remake [Raspberry Pi DHT11 Library](https://github.com/szazo/DHT11_Python) using [mraa](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa). However, sensor isn't working as well. I found [the topic on Intel forum](https://communities.intel.com/thread/53869) blaming Edison ports fast IN/OUT switching inability. The proposed solution using two wires also didn't help me.

After this introduction, a few questions come to my mind:

1. Since both Raspberry and Edison are computer systems with real
   processors and Linux (unlike the Arduino which consists of simple
   microcontroller), why are people facing a problem with DHT11 on
   Edison, while those who are using Raspberry aren't?
2. What is the source of those problems? Is it connected with
   non-deterministic OS timing on Edison (RPi has the same, hasn't
   it?), with digital pins flaw or both?
3. Is it even possible to solve this using two wires (alternatively
   with a diode)? Maybe it's impossible without a suggested tri-state
   buffer?
4. What is the simplest way to connect one-wire devices to Edison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1-Wire protocol, as you know, requires deterministic timing. 
It is not possible to do deterministic timing on a computing platform like Edison, or even a PC. You might get somewhere close to it using usleep() but your app may get interrupted at any time, thereby messing up your timings.

What you need to do when using a system without deterministic timing of GPIO is attach the sensor using an interface. That interface should use a small micro which DOES have deterministic timing. (ie a Pic, ATTINY, etc).

- OR -
  Use an existing peripheral on your system which does have deterministic timing, such as a UART.

I wrote a blog-post some years ago on how you can use a UART to do 1-Wire protocol. You should be able to find it here: http://wphost.spider-e.com/?p=231

Comment: But how can linked library work fine on RPi? It depends on fast gpio switching also.

Comment: @BartłomiejSzałach If you use proper kernel driver it might be fast enough to respond on the signal change. Otherwise you have options: 1) use additional MCU, 2) use internal MCU, though it's quite slow, 3) use Real time OS (Linux RT, Zephyr, etc).